# How to assign an array received from server to a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, frontend

I got frontend-backend implementation. I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to assign the values received from backend to a javascript array.

On my frontend I got this script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var choices = [];


        var x = document.createElement("SELECT");
        x.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
        x.setAttribute("name", "oldbaldate");
        document.body.appendChild(x);

        for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i = i + 1) {
            var z = document.createElement("option");
            z.setAttribute("value", choices[i]);
            var t = document.createTextNode(choices[i]);
            z.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(z);
        }
        $(x).appendTo('#selectOldBalance');
    });
</script>
```

and I try to figure out how to make this script to send a request to the backend, (/api/v0/requestInfo), then take the values and put them into javascript "var choices = []" array. The response received from backend will be sent in body, something like this: "2020-05-06 2020-05-07 2020-05-08 2020-05-09 ..." (the number of elements will change from a request to another). Or if it is easier I can put it into a json.

I have tried this one, but don't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let promise = fetch("http://127.0.0.1:35980/returnBalancesDates")
        const choices =  promise.split(' ');
        var x = document.createElement("SELECT");
        x.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
        x.setAttribute("name", "oldbaldate");
        document.body.appendChild(x);

        for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i = i + 1) {
            var z = document.createElement("option");
            z.setAttribute("value", choices[i]);
            var t = document.createTextNode(choices[i]);
            z.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(z);
        }
        $(x).appendTo('#selectOldBalance');
    });
</script>
```

the body response from server is a string like this: 2020-05-02 2020-05-05 2020-05-07 2020-05-15 2020-05-16

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect you mean you want to create a GET request and expect a Text result from the server at `/api/v0/requestInfo`. Do you expect Text or JSON or some other format? When do you need these details, when the page loads?

Comment: I expect text: It looks like this: Headers: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 May 2020 23:39:02 GMT
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 , and Body: 2020-05-02 2020-05-05 2020-05-07 2020-05-15 2020-05-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```
$(function() {
  function getChoices(){
    var c = [];
    $.get("/api/v0/requestInfo", function(txt){
      var parts = txt.split(" ");
      $.each(parts, function(k, v){
        c.push(v);
      });
    });
    return c;
  }
  var choices = getChoices();
  var x = $("<select>", {
    id: "mySelect",
    name: "oldbalddate"
  }).appendTo("#selectOldBalance");
  $.each(choices, function(k, v){
    $("<option>").val(v).html(v).appendTo(x);
  }); 
});
```

When `getChoices()` is run, an AJAX GET Request is run and requests data from a URL. Assuming this data is a String, like so: `2020-05-06 2020-05-07 2020-05-08 2020-05-09`, we can iterate over it and split it with a delimiter `" "`. It should return an array of data:

```
[
  "2020-05-06",
  "2020-05-07",
  "2020-05-08",
  "2020-05-09"
];
```

We can then iterate this new array to create Option elements. This will result in the following HTML.

```
<select id="mySelect" name="oldbalddate">
  <option value="2020-05-06">2020-05-06</option>
  <option value="2020-05-07">2020-05-07</option>
  <option value="2020-05-08">2020-05-08</option>
  <option value="2020-05-09">2020-05-09</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to use this one, the request arrives on server but the drop down from html page is empty. Don't figure out why

Comment: @Andrei I would review the payload from the Network tab in your browsers Console. Or Echo response to console: `console.log(txt);`